# Is there a way to dynamically modify methods in Rust?

Tags: rust, neural-network

I have a struct, `Node`, of which one of the fields (`node_type`) is an enum `LayerType` (which is either `LayerType::ReLU`, `LayerType::Sigmoid`, `LayerType::Tanh` or `LayerType::Linear`). There is a function on each Node: `non_linear_function(&self, x: f64) -> f64` which should select the correct function to use based on the variant of the `LayerType` stored in `node_type`. The code I currently have is:

```
    pub fn non_linear_function(&self, x: f64) -> f64 {
        match self.node_type {
            LayerType::ReLU => todo!(),
            LayerType::Sigmoid => todo!(),
            LayerType::Tanh => todo!(),
            LayerType::Linear => todo!(), 
        }
    }
```

However, I am not sure whether or not this is efficient. Will it perform the check every time the function is called? If so, is there a way to prevent this happening?

All of the relevant code can be found below.

```
struct Layer {
    layer_type: LayerType,
    layer_width: usize,
    node_vec: Vec<Node>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    prev_layer_size: usize,
    node_type: LayerType,
    weights: Vec<f64>,
    bias: f64
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(prev_layer_size: usize, layer_pointer: &Layer) -> Node {
        // Instantiates a new node based on the size of the previous layer
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        return Node {
            prev_layer_size,
            node_type: (*layer_pointer).layer_type,
            weights: (0..prev_layer_size).map(|x| rng.gen()).collect(),
            bias: rng.gen()
        };
    }

    pub fn eval(&self, prev_activations: &Vec<f64>) -> f64 {
        // Evaluate the activation of the node 
        return self.non_linear_function(
            self.weights.iter().zip(prev_activations.iter()).map(
                |(&x, &y)| x*y
            ).sum::<f64>() + self.bias
        )
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self, target: f64) -> Vec<f64> {
        // Changes weights and biases based on target,
        // which indicates how much a given node should change and
        // returns a vector for how it thinks the nodes in the layer
        // behind it should change
        todo!()
    }

    // The code in question is here
    pub fn non_linear_function(&self, x: f64) -> f64 {
        match self.node_type {
            LayerType::ReLU => todo!(),
            LayerType::Sigmoid => todo!(),
            LayerType::Tanh => todo!(),
            LayerType::Linear => todo!(), 
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum LayerType {
    ReLU,
    Sigmoid,
    Tanh,
    Linear
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to implement this without match? Or is the match already optimised away by the compiler?
Additionally, I can see that it is also an option to implement several different versions of `Node`, for each different `LayerType`, however this does not sound like a good idea.
I also understand that this is probably a miniscule time save, but I am writing this code to learn how to write fast Rust code.

Answer (score 1):

> > Will it perform the check every time the function is called?

Yes, with this code the check will be kept at runtime.

> > If so, is there a way to prevent this happening?

Instead of using an enum for the `LayerType`, use a trait that specifies the method `non_linear_function` and implement it for the activation functions you want to support, this will move the check at compile time.

```rust
pub trait ActivationFunction {
    fn non_linear_function(&self, x: f64) -> f64;
}

struct ReLU;

impl ActivationFunction for ReLU {
    fn non_linear_function(&self, x: f64) -> f64 {
        f64::max(0.0, x)
    }
}

// ...

self.node_type.non_linear_function(x)

// ...
```

Comment: What is the type of `self.node_type`? `ReLU` and nothing else? how can we choose something else? Or `Box<dyn ActivationFunction>`? In this last case dynamic dispatch comes into play and it's even worse than matching an enum. Or you make `Layer` and `Node` generic on `ActivationFunction`?

Comment: @prog-fh the type of `node_type` is generic and implements the trait `ActivationFunction` so `struct Node<T: ActivationFunction>`.
This will get statically dispatched at compile time, here is an example: https://gist.github.com/rust-play/f3ddaeced77dde1056b35c36dfe74e19

Comment: One other option is to make `Node` generic over T and not store an instance of `T` but `PhantomData<T>`. Then implement the trait over Node<T> (e.g. `impl ActivationFunction for Node<ReLU>`). I'd prefer to avoid this solution unless T isn't empty.

Answer (score 0):

We can see in your code that `node_type` in `Node` is probably redundant with `layer_type` in `Layer`: the non-linear function should then be chosen at the `Layer` level.

If your concern is efficiency, I suggest you step away from this OO-like design.
Instead of asking **each** node of the layer « how would you do that? » and obtaining the same behaviour for each one, you could put all the logic in the layer and consider the nodes as simple passive structs (and even go further by packing properties as suggested in [data-oriented-design](https://www.dataorienteddesign.com/dodbook/)).

The key is that the details of the computation are known once for all for the entire layer, then the compiler can generate some linear code with no branching/indirection.

In the following code, I tried to stay as close as possible to the example you provided.
The `eval()` function in `Node` does **not** apply the non-linear function.
Instead, I added an `eval()` function in `Layer`, which chooses once for all the non-linear function (I used dummy formulas) to apply to each node.
The `Node` struct does not need to hold the `LayerType` since it is already held in the `Layer`.
It does not either need to keep `prev_layer_size` since it is redundant with `weights.len()`.

Note however that the inner-product of `weight` and `prev_activations` will likely take much more time than the `match` to choose the non-linear function to be applied right after; the efficiency gain expected on the way we specify this function may not be substantial in the end...

```rust
struct Layer {
    layer_type: LayerType,
    layer_width: usize,
    node_vec: Vec<Node>,
}

impl Layer {
    pub fn eval(
        &self,
        prev_activations: &Vec<f64>,
    ) -> Vec<f64> {
        let eval_nodes =
            self.node_vec.iter().map(|n| n.eval(prev_activations));
        match self.layer_type {
            LayerType::ReLU => {
                let fnct = |x| 2.0 * x; // dummy formula
                eval_nodes.map(fnct).collect()
            }
            LayerType::Sigmoid => {
                let fnct = |x| 2.0 * x; // dummy formula
                eval_nodes.map(fnct).collect()
            }
            LayerType::Tanh => {
                let fnct = |x| 2.0 * x; // dummy formula
                eval_nodes.map(fnct).collect()
            }
            LayerType::Linear => {
                let fnct = |x| 2.0 * x; // dummy formula
                eval_nodes.map(fnct).collect()
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    weights: Vec<f64>,
    bias: f64,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(
        prev_layer_size: usize,
        layer_pointer: &Layer,
    ) -> Node {
        // Instantiates a new node based on the size of the previous layer
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        Node {
            weights: (0..prev_layer_size).map(|x| rng.gen()).collect(),
            bias: rng.gen(),
        }
    }

    pub fn eval(
        &self,
        prev_activations: &Vec<f64>,
    ) -> f64 {
        // Evaluate the activation of the node
        // NOTE: the non linear function is not used here
        self.weights
            .iter()
            .zip(prev_activations.iter())
            .map(|(&x, &y)| x * y)
            .sum::<f64>()
            + self.bias
    }

    pub fn update(
        &mut self,
        target: f64,
    ) -> Vec<f64> {
        // Changes weights and biases based on target,
        // which indicates how much a given node should change and
        // returns a vector for how it thinks the nodes in the layer
        // behind it should change
        todo!()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
enum LayerType {
    ReLU,
    Sigmoid,
    Tanh,
    Linear,
}
```